# limit records in a cross join by customer effective date

Tags: sql-server, cross-join

In SQL Server 2012, I am tring to recreate a detailed sales transaction record from two tables that have historical summary information but can't seem to limit the records based on an customer start date.  (Actually there are 3 tables, one with customer item categories and % of sales by category, but I'm not having trouble with that part of the cross join). Any help would be appreciated.

Imagine two table:

```
Customer
ID  Customername    Sales_Monthly   Date_start
1   Acme            $80,000.00      1/15/2012
2   Universal       $50,000.00      1/3/2013
3   SuperMart       $12,000.00      4/14/2013
```

```
Calendar
ID  Date
1   1 /31/2014
2   2 /28/2014
3   3 /31/2014
4   4 /30/2014
5   5 /30/2014
6   6 /30/2014
7   7 /30/2014
8   8 /30/2014
9   9 /30/2014
10  10/30/2014
11  11/30/2014
12  12/30/2014
```

A simple cross join:

```
SELECT Calendar.Date, Customer.ID, Customer.Customername, Customer.Sales_2013
FROM Calendar, Customer
```

produces 36 entries as you'd expect (3 customers x 12 months)

However, I only want to produce entries 28 entries, where [Calendar.Date] > [Customer.Date_start]

I can't seem to find WHERE CLAUSE and any join type or subquery that will limit my records based on the Customer.Date_start field.  Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Based on your sample data, why would there only be 28 results?   All calendar.Date values are > all customer.Date_Start values.

Comment: All the calendar entries are > than the start date since they are 2013 and 2012.

Comment: First select the Calendar.Date where it is greater than Customer.Date_start and put all those records into a temporary table. Then cross join that temporary table with your Customer table.

Comment: try this, looks like you gave 2014 calendar, instead of 2013. SELECT Calendar.Date, Customer.ID, 
       Customer.Customername, Customer.Sales_Monthly
FROM Calendar
CROSS JOIN Customer
where Calendar.Date > Customer.Date_Start

Comment: By `[Calendar.Date] > [Customer.Date_start]`, did you meant `MONTH([Calendar.Date]) > MONTH([Customer.Date_start])`?  Also, I see no reason for this to be a cross join.  As soon as you specify logic like [Calendar.Date] > [Customer.Date_start], you're talking about an inner join, not a cross join.

Answer (score 0):

If you're joining on a field in a cross join, it's no longer a cross join. Assuming your customer data in the question is incorrect, and you meant it to be 2014 on all the customer records, you can do the join like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer a
    JOIN Calendar b ON b.Date > a.Date_start
```

This produces 33 rows (12 for customer 1, 12 for customer 2, and 9 for customer 3, not 28 like you're expecting), but hopefully my answer will point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks.  Thanks for your elegantly simple answer. Obviously, I didn't try that in all my attempts.  I think I always had the customer date_start first so was creating the wrong join type.  (I realize that by specifying a condition, it's no longer a cross join, but the concept is similar and I thought it was the best way to get the question categorized correctly. )